# java.security.KeyException: Bad Data. while decrypt

Tags: java, security

I am trying to decrypt my value its give me java.security.KeyException: Bad Data. Exception see code and stack trace

**Code :**

```
 public String Decrypt(String text, String pubkey,PrivateKey privatekey ) {
        KeyStore keyStoreBrowser = null;
        String decryptedString;
        Cipher cipher = null;
        byte[] encryptText= new byte[256];
        try {
            keyStoreBrowser =  KeyStore.getInstance("Windows-MY");//, "SunMSCAPI");
            keyStore.load(null, null);
            String msg=null;
            if (keyStoreBrowser != null) {
                    if (privatekey != null) {
                        if (text != null) {
                            encryptText = this.bASE64Decoder.decodeBuffer(text);
                            cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding",keyStoreBrowser.getProvider());
                            cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, privatekey);
                            decryptedString = new String(cipher.doFinal(encryptText));
                        } 
                    } 
                }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println( e.getMessage());
        }
        return decryptedString;
    }
```

**stacktrace**

```
java.security.ProviderException: java.security.KeyException: Bad Data.
at sun.security.mscapi.RSACipher.doFinal(RSACipher.java:310)
at sun.security.mscapi.RSACipher.engineDoFinal(RSACipher.java:334)
at javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(Cipher.java:2165)
at SecApplet.Decrypt(SecApplet.java:1071)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin.javascript.Trampoline.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin.javascript.JSClassLoader.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.liveconnect.JavaClass$MethodInfo.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.liveconnect.JavaClass$MemberBundle.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.liveconnect.JavaClass.invoke0(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.liveconnect.JavaClass.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.main.client.LiveConnectSupport$PerAppletInfo$DefaultInvocationDelegate.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.main.client.LiveConnectSupport$PerAppletInfo$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at sun.plugin2.main.client.LiveConnectSupport$PerAppletInfo.doObjectOp(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.main.client.LiveConnectSupport$PerAppletInfo$LiveConnectWorker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Caused by: java.security.KeyException: Bad Data.

at sun.security.mscapi.RSACipher.encryptDecrypt(Native Method)
at sun.security.mscapi.RSACipher.doFinal(RSACipher.java:302)
```

And provider is SunMSCAPI

please help me to figure out this.
correct me if my code need to update.